# allowing the user to create PDF documents

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

I am new to the PDF generation but have a project to do. In my project the user should be able to create PDF documents. I have searched a lot a found sites/tutorials on creating PDF documents using `itextsharp`. But they have shown examples of creating simple PDF documents i.e. hello world.
What I want is blank editor(for that am using `ckeditor`) and user write data into that blank editor and when user clicks on save button file should get saved in PDf format. How can I do so?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is HTML to PDF conversion which can be a bit of a painful fiddle. It can be done however checkout my colleagues blogpost on how to approach this:  http://andyck1.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/html-to-pdf-conversion-in-mvc-4.html

Comment: When having similar requirements, I used ext.net html editor along with pd4ml (HTML to PDF library)

Comment: You may have to iterate though the html generated by CKEditor and add Text Elements to the PDFObject in appropriate PDFDestinations

Comment: am not looking for conversion. AM using CKEDITOR where user can enter data. now the entered data i want to save as pdf file. I mean allowing the user to create new  PDF document

Answer (score 2):

This can help you as PDFSharp provides more function for PDF
[PDF samples](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx#WebSamples_1)

Answer (score 0):

This could get tricky if you want to preserve all the formatting that was entered into CKEditor.

From my experience the two best PDF generation libraries are [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) and [syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnet/pdf#features-overview_heading). Of the two I feel syncfusion can be easier to work with.

Basically what you'll want to do is parse your HTML and generate a similar PDF structure. Both iText and syncfusion can go straight from HTML to PDF, but if your html has an odd layout you might have to form up the PDF by hand (Using PdpPTables, Paragraph objects ect).

Comment: iText is AGPL-ed. It's hardly free for a non-open source solution.